# Change CSS of Element A if Element B is displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I'm new to JavaScript so have come up with this code through reading other posts here but I am having trouble making it work on my site (FYI I am building on Webflow).

What I want to do is this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAknb.jpg)

I've designed a carousel where if you click the text triggers on the left side then it will display different content on the right side container. The display of different information is based on CSS3 interactions that toggle the display attribute, not JavaScript.

So if Element B is displayed on the webpage, then Element A will have a bold font weight, be a darker grey, and have a blue border on the side to indicate that is the active trigger.

Here is an example of my code (since I build on Webflow, I'm recreating the html and css here myself):

```js
var elemB = document.getElementById("element-b");
var elemA = document.getElementById("element-a");
if (elemB.style.display = "inline-block") {
  elemA.style.color = "#505050";
  elemA.style.font - weight = "extra-bold";
  elemA.style.border - right = "6px solid #01aae4";
} else {
  elemA.style.color = "#878787";
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dynamic-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.on-load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-itens: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="on-load" id="on-load">Show on Load</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-1">Dynamic Content 1</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-2">Dynamic Content 2</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="element-b">Element B</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-3">Dynamic Content 3</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-4">Dynamic Content 4</div>
  <div class="carousel-left">
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-2">Link 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="element-a">Element A</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-4">Link 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-5">Link 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are clicking on the items in the left column to show the image on the right, why not just assign them a class when you click on them?

Comment: There is no Jquery in your code. There is no link handler. Not sure what is working and what part is not working. As provided, nothing is working because it is not a complete working code.

Comment: @thingEvery I need the on-click styling (the added class) to disappear once another trigger is clicked, is this possible with javascript?

Comment: @NawedKhan as I said, this is built out in webflow which generates the code for you.  Right now you can't export full code, they have this feature in beta so I had to rewrite the code myself. I simplified it for the sake of the question, and I should have referenced the links as triggers instead. You're right, there are no real html links here. I want the styling of the trigger to change when it's associated content is being displayed. The content displaying according to trigger clicks is working fine, I just can't get the styling to change properly.

Comment: @emary Yes, it's definitely possible.  When a "trigger" is clicked, remove the highlighted style from all of them and add it to the one which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to trigger the check to determine if `#element-b` is visble or not.

Below, I suggest a click event handler on `.carousel`, which is a container. Then, you can use the jQuery [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector in a `if` statement.

```js
let elemB = $("#element-b");
let elemA = $("#element-a");

// Force the element b to be showing (just for the demo here)
elemB.show()

$(document).on("click", ".carousel", function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (elemB.is(":visible")) {
      console.log("Element B is visible.")
      elemA.css({
        "color": "#505050",
        "font-weight": "extra-bold",
        "border-right": "6px solid #01aae4"
      })
    } else {
      console.log("Element B is not visible.")
      elemA.css({
        "color": "#878787"
      })
    }
  }, 350); // Ajust this timeout.
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dynamic-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.on-load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-itens: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="on-load" id="on-load">Show on Load</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-1">Dynamic Content 1</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-2">Dynamic Content 2</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="element-b">Element B</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-3">Dynamic Content 3</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-4">Dynamic Content 4</div>
  <div class="carousel-left">
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-2">Link 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="element-a">Element A</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-4">Link 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-5">Link 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now... I assume you handle the clicks or whatever event to show / hide the elements on the right side.

Comment: This almost works! I have to click it twice in order for the CSS change to take effect, since the interaction takes 0.3s to proceed. So on click, element B is technically still display:none but 0.3s after the click, it's display: inline-block.

I tried adding the setTimeout(function()... to the function you have in your code but I kept receiving a bug in the console - how would you suggest delaying the click?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Sure! I edited my answer by adding a setTimout with a 350ms delay. ;)

Answer (score 0):

- #### A)   *you did not set the style rules properly*

it should be :

```
  elemA.style.fontWeight = "extra-bold";
  elemA.style.borderRight = "6px solid #01aae4";
```

`font-weight` is in javaScript  `fontWheight` , same thing  for `border-right` being `borderRight`.

```js
var elemB = document.getElementById("element-b");
var elemA = document.getElementById("element-a");
if (elemB.style.display = "inline-block") {
  elemA.style.color = "#505050";
  elemA.style.fontWeight = "extra-bold";
  elemA.style.borderRight = "6px solid #01aae4";
} else {
  elemA.style.color = "#878787";
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dynamic-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.on-load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-itens: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="on-load" id="on-load">Show on Load</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-1">Dynamic Content 1</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-2">Dynamic Content 2</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="element-b">Element B</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-3">Dynamic Content 3</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-4">Dynamic Content 4</div>
  <div class="carousel-left">
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-2">Link 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="element-a">Element A</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-4">Link 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-5">Link 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

- #### B) *I would look for the style via `getComputedStyle()`*   and test `display:none`, so you can use any other `display` values..

possible example

```js
function test() {
var elemB = document.querySelector("#element-b");
 var test = window.getComputedStyle(elemB) ;
var elemA = document.getElementById("element-a");
  if(elemB.style.display != "none"){
    elemA.style.color = "red";
    elemA.style.fontWeight = "extra-bold";
    elemA.style.borderRight = "6px solid #01aae4";
    }
  
  else{
    elemA.style.color = "#878787";
    }
  
}
for (e of document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-left .carousel-link')) {
   e.addEventListener("click", function() {
     test();
   })
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dynamic-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.on-load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-itens: flex-end;
}
#element-b { 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="on-load" id="on-load">Show on Load</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-1">Dynamic Content 1</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-2">Dynamic Content 2</div>  
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="element-b">Element B</div>  
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-3">Dynamic Content 3</div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="dc-4">Dynamic Content 4</div>
  <div class="carousel-left">
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-2">Link 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="element-a" >Element A (click to perform test)</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-4">Link 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-link" id="link-5">Link 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```